# interaction in spring integration TCP Server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I know spring integration has TcpInboundGateway, TcpOutboundGateway and ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer to handle data coming through TCP port.

ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer works great if the TCP server needs to read all the data sent from the client and then processes it. (request and response model)

For example if the client sends 9AAPL  then Server can send the AAPL price.

I am looking for a way where the client can interact with the server without closing the connection in multiple requests.

For example: if the client sends 9AAPL then the server should send AAPL price and wait for another request from the client without closing connection. This interaction can go on till the client sends 5 or no response from a client in 50 seconds.

can you please suggest the spring integration classes (TCP Gateways, Serializers etc.) that needs to be used for this interactive behavior?

we are using spring integration 4.2.6.RELEASE version and java 8. Are those versions good enough or do we need to upgrade to newer versions?

UPDATE:
Here is my spring configuration:

```
    <bean id="connectionSerializeDeserialize" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
        connection-factory="crLfServer"
        request-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
        error-channel="errorChannel"
        reply-timeout="10000"/> <!-- reply-timeout works on inbound-gateway -->

    <int:channel id="toSA" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
        ref="myService"
        method="prepare"/>

    <int:object-to-string-transformer id="serverBytes2String"
        input-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
        output-channel="toSA"/>

    <int:transformer id="errorHandler"
        input-channel="errorChannel"
        expression="payload.failedMessage.payload + ':' + payload.cause.message"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show your configuration - what you want is the default behavior.

Only if you set `singleUse` to `true` will the gateway close the socket.

Of course, your client must not close the socket either.

Set the `soTimeout` to close the socket after receiving no requests for that time.

You don't **need** newer versions, but we always recommend using the latest (4.3.4).

Comment: Making singleUse to true is great to keep the connection open. is the second request comes through the same instance of the Serializer? When does the serializer hand of the data to ServiceActivator?

can the serializer be customized to send the data to ServiceActivator multiple times? May be thats not a clean way. Please suggest how to maintain the state between the requests? 
Thanks

Comment: `false` keeps the socket open, not `true`. The message is released when all the data is received. The default deserializer requires a 4 byte binary length; you can reduce it to 1 byte (up to 255 data bytes) via a `constructor-arg` on the serializer bean. The length has to be binary. `0x04 + 'APPL'` (or `0x00000004 + 'APPL'` with the default 4 bytes length header). With `9APPL` and a 1 byte header, the deserializer is expecting `0x39` (57) bytes of data (`0x39` is the binary value of ascii `9`). If you want the length to be ascii (rather than binary), you will need a custom (de)serializer.

Comment: With respect to state, you need to explain exactly what kind of state you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the size byte.
Example state: In the first request I can get number of shares and ticker such as 5AAPL and second requests can be just ticker such as GOOG. Second request can use the same number of shares from the first request. where to maintain the state? is it possible to maintain the number of shares in Serializer and make multiple calls to ServiceActivator?

Comment: It's probably best to keep the state in the service itself; if you need to handle multiple concurrent clients, you can store it in a map, keyed by the `ip_connectionId` message header. You can use an application event listener to detect a connection closure, allowing you to clear the state if necessary (e.g. a client dies before completing his series of requests).

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Saving in a message header is a great way.